# Java - Problem with the classpath on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I'm trying to recompile a project I've been working on and I keep getting an error message when trying to load a property file:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I guess this has to do with the classpath. But I've added the path to the file in Properties-> Java build path-> Libraries (external class).
I also checked the .classpath file generated by eclipse, and the path is really there!

Why isn't Eclipse looking at the right path?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There 2 different classpaths, build classpath and runtime classpath. The one you are setting is the build classpath.

Check your runtime classpath by going to `Run -> Run Configurations` and select your application configuration. Check the classpath setting there.

There is another workaround for this also. Eclipse by default will include your *output folder* (usually named *bin*) in your classpath. Typically anything that are not compilable in *src* folder will be copied to *bin* as is. I assumed your property file is not located in *src* folder. What you can do is to open your project property and add the folder where your property is located into `Java Buld Path -> Source (tab)`. This way eclipse will copy the content of that folder into *bin* and will be in the classpath.

Comment: why i cant see classpath in Run configuration . i am using Eclipse luna. i can see this tabs Main, Argument plugins, configuration,Tracing,Enviroment,Common.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to read a property file:

- Have it in the current working directory (the one cd'ed to).  You can do this in the Eclipse launch configuration. (Run -> Run...)
- Include it in your application, by having it in a source folder.  You then need to read it in through a class loader to be able to get it always (when jarred up, through Java Web Start, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Double check if the property file or its directory is in the excluded list of the project Source. If it is remove the exclusion filter and try recompiling.