# NoClassDefFoundError: ResponseParserRegistrar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror, rest-assured

I have put the [rest-assured-2.2.0.jar](http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/GettingStarted) in my Eclipse workspace (for an Android app) and added it to the buildpath of the project as referenced library. Then I imported:

```
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import static com.jayway.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
```

But still if I do `RestAssured.given();` I get 
`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseParserRegistrar`

If I look inside the jar file I can find a ResponseParserRegistrar.class file on the right place, so it does exist.

If I try to import it it does not complain:

```
import com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseParserRegistrar;
```

But it still gives the error.

What did I forget or do wrong?

**EDIT**

Now I've created a blank new Android app with the following MainActivity:

```
package com.example.testrestassured;

import com.example.testrestassured.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseParserRegistrar;
import com.jayway.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        RestAssured.given();
    }
}
```

The project has only one referenced library: rest-assured-2.2.0.jar (correct spelling).

Still I get the same problem

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13142): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseParserRegistrar
```

**EDIT**

Changing to rest-assured-2.3.0.jar (new version) and adding json-schema-validator-2.3.0.jar and it's big list of dependencies did not fix it either. I've tried to find the runtime classpath, but I can't find it in the menus of [ADT](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html).

Comment: It sounds like you are using some kind of IDE or building tool (e.g. Eclipse, Intellij, ant, maven..) and that the problem you are having is IDE/build-tool related. I guess you should give details about that and ad the corresponding key-words.

Comment: Could you try to reproduce the problem using a java command line invocation instead (java -cp …. myMainClass kind of thing)?

Comment: Yes I'm using Eclipse, added it to the text now.

Comment: I'm not used to compiling java from the commandline. How would I do this?

Comment: How are you actually running the program? Run menu? it seems that there is a difference between the editing/building/runtime class paths. Checkout this thread about the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520821/java-problem-with-the-classpath-on-eclipse It is about a missing property file but it is an start; if you look harder you might find a better thread.

Comment: My experience with this think is that is difficult to fix without being present due to the layer of complexity added by this otherwise very useful and helpful IDEs.

Comment: As about how to execute your program from the command line… depending on what kind of project you are working on you eventually are going to hit this issue; if you want your program to be usefully to other people it should be runnable without having Eclipse installed.

Comment: cont … for example if it is an standalone program you probably want 
Eclipse to generate a ".jar" file with your classes that can be run from the command line with the command "java -jar myprogram.jar". That is a very gross simplification cause you have to care about external library dependencies, VM parameters etc…

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that I'm working on an Android App, so I won't need to create it into a .jar file. (I left that out to focus on the issue)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you don't have more than one version of the jar. This is very common in projects using Maven, when parent projects have older versions of the libraries.

If you tell us more about your configuration it would be easier to try and find the cause.

Comment: I'll try if removing other jars fixes/changes it

Comment: If you are using Maven, check the dependency tree with mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections

Comment: Im not 100% sure what maven is, but I guess I don't use it since I use Eclipse? The other jars in my buildpath don't have the same folder structure inside them, so they can't be interfering.

Comment: Check your .classpath file. Is any entry in there for the  rest-assured-2.2.0.jar?

Answer (score 0):

Look NoClassDefFoundError is thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.

Now in above as you are having MAVEN project it might be you have not  added dependency of your rest-assured-2.2.0.jar in pom.xml.

And if you're building either Eclipse RCP or Eclipse plugin.

If yes, you should put  rest-assured-2.2.0.jar under plugin dependencies. Go to plugin.xml, Runtime and put  rest-assured-2.2.0.jar in the classpath.

Moreover as a cross-check please check the spelling name you used everywhere is same.