# Loading ucanaccess.jar into an Eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, jdbc, eclipse-rcp

I am having trouble with the class loader trying to convince an Eclipse RCP application to load the UCanAccess JDBC driver. This works fine in a standard Java application, but I'm having trouble (ClassNotFoundException when I try to use Class.forName()) and java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:ucanaccess://path without it. This probably comes down to properly specifying the class path to the RCP application, which does not appear to use the CLASSPATH variable or -classpath to the JVM.

Comment: The jar has to be included in a plug-in, and be in the `Bundle-Classpath` of the plug-in. See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44196191/2670892)

Comment: Thanks. That was the missing piece. Having it in CLASSPATH also appears to have interfered with some ECLIPSE function in 2021-09. ./bin has to be in the definition also for an RCP project to retain the project classes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.