# Maven Dependency classes are not resolved in runtime eclipse during plugin development

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, grpc-java, eclipse-pde

I am trying to create an Eclipse plugin-in project. The functionality of the plug-in is to simply send a gRPC request to another server.

So, I have included the required Maven Dependencies as below:

(Based on the documentation, https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java#readme )

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
        <version>1.41.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
        <version>1.41.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
        <version>1.41.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- necessary for Java 9+ -->
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.53</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But when I try to launch the application in runtime-Eclipse, the gRPC dependencies are not resolved and so I am getting the below error:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2021-10-28 08:19:37.492
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'grpcclientmyplugin.parts.SampleView' from bundle '23'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/grpc/Channel
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:414)
```

I think the Maven Dependencies are not detected by the launched Eclipse Application.

But if I create a normal maven project and execute it, everything is working fine.

I am not sure what needs to be configured (something like Target Platform or VM arguments) so that I can create an Eclipse plug-in that can send gRPC requests.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can't use maven dependencies in an Eclipse plug-in. Plug-ins can only depend on other plug-ins and the dependencies must be in the MANIFEST.MF as `Require-Bundle` or `Import-Package`.

Comment: Thanks, greg, so if I want to create a plug that is expected to send a gRPC request, what is expected to be done?Please advise or share with me any documentation or tutorial related to it

Comment: You might be able to find a plug-in containing the library you need - [Eclipse Orbit](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.orbit) has a lot of prebuilt plug-ins. Or you include the jars you need in your plug-in - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44196191/2670892)

Comment: Greg, I have created a plug-in project with the "Eclipse 4 plugin" template and also a separate JAR file that has a class named "SampleClass". And as you mentioned, I am able to add "Bundle-ClassPath: lib/Sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar", which allowed me to create an object for the "SampleClass" within the plugin project (Meaning it did not throw any compile-time error). However, with the Bundle-ClassPath, the Sample Window itself is not getting created in the runtime-Eclipse. If I remove the Bundle-ClassPath and the object creation code, the default template is getting loaded properly.

Comment: Please let me know what I am missing here

Comment: I have no idea, I don't know anything about that particular package.

Comment: Greg, I have created a simple Maven Project, added a class, and generated the JAR. If possible, could you please share your mail id so that I can send you the plug-in and sample project for your reference?

Comment: Or google meet or zoom call will also work for me. Sorry to bother you much

Comment: No. I answer questions here on Stack Overflow and nowhere else. I will not be interacting any further with this question.